# xna ContentLoadException was unhandled (trying to load a texture)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I am trying to load a texture file with

`Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("assetname");`

unfortunately the program is giving me a ContentLoadException saying the texture is not found. I decided to remove the texture and add it again, but same error.

It actually even worked. Later I started the game again and this exception appeared. Maybe I accidentally changed something?

Comment: Not sure what you are actually wanting from us?  Might also need some more code to see what is going on.

Comment: maybe path of texture is wrong. if there's any.

Comment: the path of the texture is correct. thats the reason why i asked. i dont know how to get this error away.

Comment: Is the texture copy option set as Copy if newer or Always Copy ?

Comment: Did you actually add it the the content solution?? 1. Place it in the content solution directory.  2. Add->existing file-> your texture.type